# PHP regex - string contains 'facebook' with all domains

Tags: php, regex

I need to check, if users input URL contains facebook(.any domain). This is what I have:

`preg_match("/.(facebook)+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/", $input);`

But on typying `www.facebook.com` it returns false. Could someone help me with this? I am not very good in regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are only matching for uppercase letters in the last part. You may want to make it match case independent by adding a modifier:

```
preg_match("/.(facebook)+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i", $input);
```

The next things are:

1. you don't need to put "facebook" into a group
2. You don't need to quantify facebook
3. if you want to match a dot, then escape it

So end up with this:

```
preg_match("/\.facebook\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i", $input);
```

Comment: this won't match facebook.com, because of the . at the start

Comment: It won't match .co.uk either.

Comment: @i-CONICA, depends on what the OP wants to do. It will return true because it matches on "facebook.co". If the matched string needs to be reused, it would be not enough.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this along with the answer of `@stema`

```
if(strpos($url, "facebook") !== FALSE)
{
   echo "exists";
}
else
{
   echo "not exists";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already find out solution, I needed to use preg_match.

Comment: nice that may be its useful for you.

Comment: Yea, but I already know that solution (I use it in another script).